# how to get the time between User input text twice?

Tags: android, searchview

I use SearchView in my android app, I monitor the onQueryTextChange event, what i don't want to filter the result when every time user input text, I want to filter the result only when User want to filter, I solution is to get the time every time user input text, when the time is bigger than 1s, I will query the result for the search, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) that resets every time the input changes.

```
Timer mTimer;

...

public boolean onQueryTextChange (String newText) {
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            search(newText);
        }
    }, 1000);

    ...
}
```

You could also use `onQueryTextSubmit` to search only when the user wants to.

Comment: But as I know It will raise `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled` error when You use the schedule method after You call `cancel` method.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot. IIRC, you have to replace the old timer with a new instance. I'll edit my answer.